# UAC and remote control

Tags: windows-7, uac

If you've developed a remote control application as I've done, you must know that screen capture doesn't capture the UAC dialog when that dialog is pop up, and as a result the control can't be continued.

Anybody know a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, I believe what you're asking about is possible.

In addition to remote control software, test automation software and accessibility apps for those with disabilities also need a way to interact with protected UI and the secure desktop.

Regarding the issues UAC presents for remote control software, see:

http://www.uvnc.com/vista/

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.platformsdk.security/browse_thread/thread/acb3a0ccb7682506/d05b0a3026366423

Those links contain info on how the UltraVNC project works around UAC.  UltraVNC is open source, so the code might be a good resource as well.

I think the solution to this type of problem probably always involves delegating high-integrity tasks to a service.  I don't think there's any other way around it (besides disabling various UAC settings).

And needless to say, writing an app that has an unusually high level of control over the system is a tricky matter - a lot of care must go into the design to make sure it's safe for use without exploitation. :)

See also:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/SubvertingVistaUAC.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/VistaSessions.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssecurity/thread/4aadadbd-fc3d-4239-ba0f-4d81f17ec938

Comment: Well I've been investigating this in recently days, and what you said is very to the point and very helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

That is the entire *point* of the UAC dialog.

So, to answer your question, "No, nobody knows - because it isn't or shouldn't be possible".

Comment: i don't think so, because in many remote control solution they can do this: i've tried logmein and techinline, they both can.