# Windows UI login screen automation

Tags: windows, authentication

I want to automate the windows UI login screen. Can somebody help me with any robust framework for automating windows login?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UI Automation Windows User login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209488/ui-automation-windows-user-login)

Comment: I am looking for more in depth like if we have a some classes to send text to the login screen